# Movie filter by categories with React/Js and an API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, filtering

Bonjour tout le monde, I try to make a filter by categories with React using the movie database API.
I have already made a request on which I make a .map to display all the movies ranked by popularity order.
I have a "Genres" component in which I get the genres names and "TopFilms" component that is the parent of "Genres" component, that display all of movies ranked by popularity.
So I have a "getFilms" request in "TopFilms" component and a request for genres names in the "Genres" component. 
I would like when I click on one of the genres of the "Genres" component, the getFilms function and the "TopFilms" component will update with the corresponding genre.

**Here is my TopFilms component (I removed some things for better readability):**

- my url for all movies ranked by popularity:

```
const baseUrlDiscover = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_MOVIE_DB_API_KEY}&sort_by=popularity.desc&language=en-US`;
```

- My constructor, functions getFilms() and updateCurrentCategory() for update genres:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      films: [],
      page: 1,
      loading: false,
      genres: [],
      currentCategory: null
    };
    this.getFilms = this.getFilms.bind(this)
    this.btnClickPrev = this.btnClickPrev.bind(this)
    this.btnClickNext = this.btnClickNext.bind(this)
  }
  getFilms(categoryId= ''){
    const { page } = this.state
    this.setState({
      films: [],
      loading: true,
    })
    Axios.get(`${baseUrlDiscover}&page=${page}&with_genres=${categoryId}`)
    .then((response) => {
      this.setState({
        films: response.data.results,
        loading: false
      })
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
      this.setState({
        films: [],
        loading: false
      })
    })
  }
  updateCurrentCategory = (id) => {
    this.setState({currentCategory: id})
  }
```

- My componentDidMount() with getFilms() function (I think I have to add a componentDidUpdate but I have an "Maximum update depth exceeded" error with this last one..):

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.getFilms()
  }
```

- In the render, there is the .map to display all the movies:

```
const theMovies = this.state.films.map((film) => {
      return(
        <Grid key={film.id} item xs={6} sm={6} md={3} lg={3}>
          <Card className='container-card-poster'>
              <CardImg className={classes.cardIaamge} top width="100%" src={`${posterUrl}${film.poster_path}`} alt="Card image cap" /> 
              <figcaption className='fig-caption'>
                  <h4 className={classes.titleOverlay}>{film.title}</h4>
                </figcaption>
          </Card>
        </Grid>
      )
    })
```

**And there is my "Genres" component:**

```
const genresUrl = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_MOVIE_DB_API_KEY}&language=en-US`

class Genres extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      genres: [],
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    Axios.get(genresUrl)
    .then((response) => {
      this.setState({genres: response.data.genres})
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props
    return (
      <PopupState variant="popover" popupId="demo-popup-menu">
      {popupState => (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Button
            variant="contained" {...bindTrigger(popupState)}
            href=""
            target="_blank"
            className={classes.navLink}
          >
            Genres <ExpandMoreIcon className={classes.icons} />
          </Button>
          <Menu {...bindMenu(popupState)} onClick={popupState.close}>
            {
              this.state.genres.map((genre) => {
                return  <AnchorLink key={genre.id} href='#pop'>
                          <MenuItem className={classes.menuItemGenres} onClick={()=> this.props.updateCurrentCategory(genre.id)}>{genre.name}</MenuItem>
                        </AnchorLink>

              })
            }
          </Menu>
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
    </PopupState>
    )
  }
}
```

Sorry for my english that is not very good, I tried to be as clear as possible and thanks in advance for your help.
Have a nice day !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use `didUpdate()` like so:

```js
componentDidUpdate(_prevProps, prevState) {
   if (this.state.currentCategory !== prevState.currentCategory) {
      this.getFilms();
   }
}
```

Let me know if it helped.

Comment: Hi @RafaelRocha, indeed your solution works perfectly. They say in the documentation that you have to put a condition.. I should have read the doc haha ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: Can you upvote please? Need them badges heheh
Since it helped. Glad it did!